# RecursionError in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a simple 'guess the number' game in Python without any difficulty, so I wanted to challenge myself and take it one step further. I tried to make it in Tkinter, and add in 'guesses' and 'timer' variables.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
import random

guesses = 0
timeleft = 30

numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
numbers2 = []

doTick = True

def startGame(event):
    global doTick

    doTick = True

    number = random.choice(numbers)
    numbers.remove(number)
    numbers2.append(number)

    if timeleft == 30:
        countdown()

    wrong_guess()

def wrong_guess():

    global score
    global timeleft
    global guesses

    if timeleft > 0:
        e.focus_set()

        if int(e.get()) == int(numbers2[0]):
            guesses += 1
            guessesLabel.config(text="Guesses: " + str(guesses))
            correct_guess()
        else:
            if int(e.get()) > int(numbers2[0]):
                Label.config(text="Your guess is too high!")
                guesses += 1
                guessesLabel.config(text="Guesses: " + str(guesses))
                wrong_guess()
            else:
                Label.config(text="Your guess is too low!")
                guesses += 1
                guessesLabel.config(text="Guesses: " + str(guesses))
                wrong_guess()

        e.delete(0, tkinter.END)

def countdown():

    global timeleft

    if not doTick:
        return

    if timeleft > 0:
        timeleft -= 1
        timeLabel.config(text="Time left:" + str(timeleft))
        root.after(1000, countdown)

def correct_guess():

    global guesses
    global timeleft
    global doTick

    doTick = False

    guessesLabel.config(text="You correctly guessed the number in " + str(guesses) + " guesses!")

    timeLabel.config(text="You had " + str(timeleft) + " seconds to spare!")

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Guess the Number")
root.state('zoomed')

timeLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="", fg="red",font=('Helvetica',25))
timeLabel.pack()

guessesLabel = tkinter.Label(root,text="", fg="green",font=('Helvetica',25))
guessesLabel.pack()

Label = tkinter.Label(root, text="", fg="blue",font=('Helvetica',25))
Label.pack()

e = tkinter.Entry(root)
root.bind('<Return>',startGame)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

My problem is that, when the program runs, the following error message appears:

**RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object**

My best guess is that there is something slightly wrong with the [def](/questions/tagged/def) statements, but I am unsure of where this occurs and how this would be fixed.

This is the error message, for those of you who were asking:

Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
 RESTART: C:\Users\Acer_PC\MINCH\Year 10\Computing\python\guess the number.py Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer_PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1549, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)

Comment: Could you please post the traceback (with the hundreds of repeating lines at the end removed)?

Comment: This is the error message that pops up before the hundreds of repeating lines: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer_PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @RhysMinchin could you please **edit your question** to include the traceback? (it is really hard to read in a comment)

Comment: Please post that data in the question. Also, that isn't the full traceback. What comes before the frame you mentioned

Comment: I'm guessing that `if timeleft > 0:` and then `if int(e.get()) > int(numbers2[0]):` is just always coming True, both are conditionals in `wrong_guess` that lead to a recursive call to `wrong_guess`

Comment: yep, `wrong_guess` is calling itself indefinitely so long as `int(e.get()) == int(numbers2[0])` is False.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen could you please post this as an answer, along with a possible way of fixing the wrong_guess issue? (This is so I can vote up your answer as I believe this is the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `wrong_guess` is calling itself, this is frequently used in terminal programs to signal "go back to beginning of the function and try again" but it is not considered good practice and certainly does not work unless waiting for the user to enter something is part of the function. (as you have witnessed)

Consider when the function `wrong_guess` should really be called, it would make sense to check the users guess every time they press the `<Return>` key (and the program is already started)

```
def press_enter_callback(e=None):
    if doTick:
        #game is running
        wrong_guess() #might be better to call it "check_guess"
    else:
        startGame(e) #if there is no countdown clock then start a new game

root.bind('<Return>',press_enter_callback)
```

Then removing the two calls to `wrong_guess` in `wrong_guess` since they make no sense.

Your code is also missing some conditional that will reset the timer or set `doTick = False` when the countdown reaches 0